# How to use another javascript file in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How to use the functions of a javascript file in contentscript.js? I have some functions in a1.js and I want to know how to call those in contentscript.js

a1.js is also part of extension and is in the same folder as contentscript.js

Comment: is a1.js part of the extension or is it on the page?

Comment: It's part of the extension and it's also in the same folder as contentscript.js

Answer (score 4):

Put them in your `manifest.json` file:

```
  ....
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["a1.js", "contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ....
```

`a1.js` will be loaded first, then `contentscript.js`.

Example:

```
// a1.js
function x() { return 100; }
alert(typeof y); // undefined, because `contentscript.js` is not loaded yet
setTimeout( function(){alert(typeof y;)}, 1000 ); // function

// contentscript.js
function y() {
    alert(x()); // Shows 100
}
```

Comment: PS. `y` has not been called yet, so `100` doesn't show up. If you want to call it, add `y();` in `contentscript.js`.